# Session.contains return false for object that load by OneToMany relation

Tags: java, hibernate, session, orm, hibernate-mapping

consider there exists two object `A`and `B` where `A` contains a OneToMany relation with `B`. I Load Object A and iterate on its `B`s. but the problem is that when i call `Session.contains(B[0])` it returns `false`.

in previous session i had load object `b (b=B[0])` and in this session before loading object `A` I have called `b2=Session.merge(b)` and here when i load Object `A` again, it fills `B` field with `b` instead of `b2`;

does any body know why it fills `B` with `b` instead of `b2`?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a Set as your one-to-many collection and your equals/hashCode is using the database identifier.

When you add an element to the set, the hashCode is used to place the lement in the right bucket. Once you flush the session, the identifier is assigned and so the hashCode changes. But the object is still placed in the old hashCode bucket. When you'll try to load it with the new hashCode value you won't see you object any more.

That's why you need to [use a business key](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-equals-and-hashcode/) when implementing equals/hashCode in your domain model Entities or [use this trick if you don't have any business key](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/).

Comment: No. I have an ArrayList as my OneToMany Collection

Comment: Are you using the entity to implement equals and hashcode?

Comment: Yes. I use these: 

    `public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Message message = (Message) o;

        if (id != message.id) return false;

        return true;
    }`

and

    `public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    }`

Comment: If you are using synthetic auto-incremented identifiers (IDENTITY, SEQUENCE, TABLE sequence) then you need to switch to using a business key instead. The hashCode/equals will not be consistent before and after inserting an entity.

Comment: @VladMihalcea I just ran into this freaking issue. Is this true, even when you have already implemented your equals and hashcode not to care about any collections? I am just comparing one unique String key. And this is happening on a non unique generated key. saveOrUpdate seems to be fine with it though, but contains return false.